# Does Github have a branch equivalent to a folder symbolic link?

Tags: github, git-branch

So with folders you can create a symbolic link that points to another path like this

```
➜  example ln -s tmp symlink
➜  example ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   4 sethmcclaine  staff   128 Aug  5 14:39 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 58 sethmcclaine  staff  1856 Aug  5 14:39 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 sethmcclaine  staff     3 Aug  5 14:39 symlink -> tmp
drwxr-xr-x   3 sethmcclaine  staff    96 Aug  5 14:38 tmp
```

Is there a way to do something similar with git branches?

**Situation**
We have a branch `feature-deploy` that deploys to a staging environment.
Assume we have multiple feature branches (ex `feat-a`, `feat-b`, `feat-c`)
Instead of replacing `feature-deploy` with the content of different features is there a way to just have it point to another branch?

Answer (score 1):

Git has the concept of symbolic references, or symrefs.  These are like symlinks in that they point to another ref, but they are stored differently than actual symlinks on the system, since Windows usually requires elevated privileges for symlinks.  The most common example, when it is pointing at a branch, is `HEAD`.

However, the Git protocol doesn't offer a way to push these or modify them.  They can be listed and read over the protocol, but not modified.  As a consequence, you'd need a GitHub-specific way to create and modify them, and GitHub doesn't offer one except for `HEAD` (the default branch).